# Visual Basic developer wants to write Linux applications

Tags: python, linux, vb.net, visual-studio, raspberry-pi

I am trying to choose a language, IDE and other tools in order to develop a photo gallery application for a Linux platform. Specifically the [Raspberry Pi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi) running 
[Debian 6.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian#Release_history) (Squeeze).

My background is almost exclusively using Visual Basic since the early 1990 and most recently VB.NET in [Visual Studio 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2008).

I've tried developing in Visual Studio 2008 and running the application on the target machine using [Mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29), but I have come across a few issues early on that doesn't give me much confidence in this route. I do love the fact I can use Visual Studio and Visual Basic though.

I am considering learning Python and using one of the GUI tool kits like [Tkinter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tkinter) or [Glade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glade_Interface_Designer) for [GTK+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTK+), but I am confused as there seems to be a vast array of options.

What route should I take developing applications for Linux which has:

1. The smallest learning curve for someone comming from Visual Basic.
2. Maximum ease/speed of development (productivity) rather than speed or efficiency of finished application.

I have complete control of the target computer, so I don't care about installation or distribution issues.

Comment: Depending on your needs, you might consider looking into Mono.  It can run *most* .NET assemblies with only a handful of changes to code.  (Of course, it depends entirely on your application.  Your results may vary.)  I don't think I'd distribute an application requiring Mono, but if you just want to play around a bit, it might be useful to you.

Comment: @Brad: Given the Raspi's limited resources (700MHz ARM, 256MB RAM) is Mono a good idea? (I've never used it, so I'm not sure how "heavy" it is.)

Comment: @Li-aungYip, Oh, I completely missed that he was running it on a Raspberry.  No, Mono is not a good idea.  :-D

Comment: Why is mono no good on 700MHz ARM, 256MB RAM?  RAM useage?

Comment: Actually [Mono might be OK](http://www.mono-project.com/Small_footprint).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is probably as good as you're going to get, so far as "ease of learning" is concerned.

As far as the choice of GUI toolkit goes, I think `wxWidgets` might be the easiest to get off the ground with. Try Jan Bodnar's [wxPython tutorial](http://zetcode.com/wxpython/). He also has tutorials for PyGTK and Tkinter (amongst others) if you wanted to look at those for comparison.

Comment: Can the person(s) that closed this question explain to me how it is not about programming or which FAQ it does not comply with?  Or, please re-open as i would very much like to get more answers to this question.

Comment: @Guy: The close reason isn't the one I would have chosen. I would have closed it as: **not constructive** -
This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

Comment: @Guy: The reason I would have closed it is because there is no "right answer" - only opinions, like the opinion I gave. We can't answer it with code, and the question is too broad to make specific recommendations.

Comment: @Li-aungYip And yet you attempted to answer it.